# Center JDialog plugin in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, jdialog, intellij-plugin

I'm currently programming a plugin for IntelliJ, but have lost the basic of how to center a new JDialog in front of IntelliJ window. That is that I create and open a new JDialog and it should initially center in the IDE, even if I change the monitor. Atm I run "setLocationRelativeTo(null);" and it's just opening on my primary screen all the time and not in the IDE. Anyone got any idea what I'm missing?

**Edit**

I tried to get the parents position and use the coordinate to place where the JDialog should be. But it always displays on the upper left corner of my primary screen and not where I have my IDE.

```
    Point parentPoint = getParent().getLocation();
    Dimension parentDimension = getParent().getSize();
    Dimension dialogDimension = getSize();
    int x = (int) (parentPoint.getX() + (parentDimension.getWidth() - dialogDimension.getWidth()) / 2);
    int y = (int) (parentPoint.getY() + (parentDimension.getHeight() - dialogDimension.getHeight()) / 2);
    setLocation(x, y);
```

Comment: Retrieve the coordinates of the IntelliJ window, as a beginning. Then calculate the coordinates for your JDialog

Comment: Great solution! But how do I retrieve the coordinates of the IntelliJ window?

Comment: Maybe the parent of your JDialog? You should try and get some documentation about that

Comment: I tried to implement that solution but still have problem with the coordinate. See edit.

Comment: Did you try setLocationRelativeTo(getParent())

Comment: Tried, but it give me the same result as setLocationRelativeTo(null). That it's only open on my primary monitor and not where I have my IDE.

Comment: getParent().getLocation() x and y coordinate is always 0.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

The problem was that I never assigned the parent window for the JDialog. Since I created the dialog through AnAction impl, I could get the project from AnActionEvent. 
I used that project variable to create this code in my JDialog implementation.

```
private Window getParentWindow(Project project) {
    WindowManagerEx windowManager = (WindowManagerEx) WindowManager.getInstance();

    Window window = windowManager.suggestParentWindow(project);
    if (window == null) {
        Window focusedWindow = windowManager.getMostRecentFocusedWindow();
        if (focusedWindow instanceof IdeFrameImpl) {
            window = focusedWindow;
        }
    }
    return window;
}
```

Then just calling this method to

```
setLocationRelativeTo(getParentWindow(project));
```